# is 100s of processes in htop common for 4 workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, memory-leaks, resque

I've got 2 projects using Resque that i inherited, so i am just looking to see if it's normal or if the 220+ process/thread (whatever `htop` actually is reporting) is normal.

Now `top` only shows 4 `Ss` and 4 `Sl` processes. Totalling 8.  `htop` shows:

```
23117 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.06 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23148 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.16 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23151 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:01.15 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23594 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.05 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23605 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.05 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23613 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.05 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23638 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.04 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23741 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.04 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23783 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.04 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
23794 deploy     20   0 1428M  162M  8812 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.05 resque-1.25.2: Waiting for critical,high,low
.... and on and on.....
```

This goes on for hundreds. It also builds over time, and i can't confirm if these get killed or what, but let's say after a restart there are 20, within minutes of jobs running it goes into the hundred(s).

My other reference project uses Resque and resque_scheduler and in it's `htop` it only has like 12 (one for each worker) and does not grow in memory.

Does your Resque do this? I have not touched any config at all, there isn't really an initializer anymore, meaning it's just running resque's starting rake task and that is it.

I ask because i think we have a memory leak and found out that Puma is leaking on one box, but this box only runs Resque and I noticed this while deep diving today.  Bonus points if you know how to find a memory leak in Resque based jobs.
[image: Boundary Memroy Usage graph]

This graph shows, over time, that memory continues to go up and up. I have no real config to show either, as I did have the standard `before_fork` connection config for ActiveRecord connections. i thought that was the culprit, somehow as i grasped at straws, and got rid of it. As  you can see in this graph the first stanza has memory growth and that is with the config and the second restart is without, yet it still increases in memory.

If you use Resque, can you verify your memory does not grow over time and does  your htop show that similar amount of threads? If not, can you think of what may be causing this behaviour?